# Вывод символа через промежуток времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Есть код, который должен выводить каждый новый символ через N секунд(допустим 5 символов в секунду). Есть код пример(так мало, потому - что всё остальное - базовые блоки), так вот, каким лучше образом написать на экране любой текст: с помощью последовательного добавления символа или есть встроенный способ в модуле?

```
for i in range(text):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            screen.blit(text, place)
```

Comment: первый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import time

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 720))

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 32)

def f(text, time_, font, x, y):
    tick = time_ / len(text)

    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        win.blit(font.render(text[:i + 1], 1, (200, 200, 200)), (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(tick)

f("Hello, World", 1, font, 0, 0)
```

принимает 5 параметров:

- `text` это что мы будем отрисовывать
- `time_` в течении сколько времени будем отрисовывать
- `font` шрифт для отрисовки
- `x` и `y` это координаты для отрисовки

---

вот пример программы которая будет писать `"Hello, World!!!` при каждом нажатии на экран

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 720))

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 32)

def f(text, time_, font, x, y):
    tick = time_ / len(text)

    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        win.blit(font.render(text[:i + 1], 1, (200, 200, 200)), (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(tick)

y = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            y += 25
            f("Hello, World!!!", .5, font, 0, y)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Каждый раз выручаете)

Comment: А, ещё вопрос,куда её запихнуть в обработчике событий, чтобы он(текст) вечно не отрисовывалась?